# \choose in \frac doesn't work

Tags: errors

I'm trying to type following:

```
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{{n-1} \choose {|A_i|-1}} \leq 1
```

But complier alerts:

```
Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atopwithdelims;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 57.

! Ambiguous; you need another { and }.
\choose ->\atopwithdelims ()
```

However `{n-1} \choose {|A_i|-1}` works.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. In particular, the error suggests you are using `amsmath` with LaTeX, and therefore shouldn't be using `\choose` (plain TeX syntax).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `amsmath` loaded, the call `\frac{A}{B}` translates into

```
{\begingroup A\endgroup \@@over B}
```

where `\@@over` is the primitive `\over` that `amsmath` redefines.

On the other hand `\choose` translates into `\atopwithdelims()`, just like in Plain TeX, but `amsmath` will transform `\atopwithdelims` into `\primfrac{atopwithdelims}` that in turn becomes `\@@atopwithdelims` (the primitive meaning of `\atopwithdelims`) after possibly issuing, only once, the warning you have reported.

Now, in your case, `A` is `1`, which makes no problem, while `B` is

```
{n-1} \choose {|A_i|-1}
```

Thus what TeX sees next is

```
{\begingroup 1\endgroup \@@over {n-1} \@@atopwitdelims() {|A_i|-1}}
```

which is illegal syntax, because there are two fraction commands at the same level.

Knuth argues that `{A\over B}` is better than `\frac{A}{B}` (see the interview in the last issue of TUGboat), but the developers of LaTeX and `amsmath` think differently. In particular, `amsmath` issues warnings at first usage of any of the primitive fraction commands, but it accepts them, provided they don't create syntax errors during macro expansion.

You have two choices: either you *always* use the primitive commands (ignoring the warnings), or you *always* use the `amsmath` commands. Mixing them is a sure source of troubles, as you found out.

You *might* input

```
\frac{1}{{n-1 \choose |A_i|-1}}
```

but this is too complicated, because of the double braces. The form

```
{1 \over {n-1 \choose |A_i|-1}}
```

might be appealing to Knuth (not to me), but

```
\frac{1}{\binom{n-1}{|A_i|-1}}
```

is safer. Spaces can perhaps help readability:

```
\frac{ 1 }{ \binom{n-1}{|A_i|-1} }
```

By the way, the `\begingroup...\endgroup` that LaTeX adds around the numerator is meant to avoid declarations made in the numerator to leak out and affect also the denominator, a problem that the primitive syntax can't avoid without inserting manually the group. This is another reason for choosing `\frac` and the related commands.

Comment: Not only Knuth argues that `{A \over B}` is better, I argue too. The TeX source is intended not only for machine but for human too. And human reads the fraction by this way: A over B, no by this way: fraction: nominator A, denominator B. Many people creating LaTeX sources forgot this principle: "TeX source is intended for human." And they are _coding_ their documents no writing. And new layers (LyX for example) are created for simplicity this _coding_.

Comment: @wipet You don't read `1+x/2` (imagine `x/2` in fraction form) as *one plus open brace x over two closed brace*, do you? The braces are compulsory in this case, so your objection loses its appeal. The similar *square root of two* is handled by the “of” that suggests the braces. Conversely, `$1+{x \over 2}$` is counterintuitive.

Comment: @wipet After having seen several people forgetting the braces, I can testify it's counterintuitive. Problems with `\frac` are far less frequent. But this discussion takes nowhere: you have your opinion based on years using Plain TeX, I have used LaTeX for more than twenty years and never found `\frac` counterintuitive.

Comment: Human does a pause (or breathe in) in the occurence of the boundary of fraction. Human reads: one plus (pause) x over two (pause). These pauses are translated to braces in TeX source. It seems very simple and natural. And if the fraction is the whole expression then no pauses are needed: one over twelve, i.e. `$1\over 12$` without braces.

Comment: @wipet: If you feel it is more natural to use `\over` please do; then at least somebody enjoys Knuth's choice. I am a plain TeX user (too) so I'll use `\over`, but at times I wish I had `\frac` (if only because `\frac1x` is less keystrokes than `{1\over x}`). But beyond personal preference, having `\over` (and its relatives) is a burden for the TeX machine, as it causes the numerator to change math style after being scanned; without it I see no obstruction for TeX to maintain a "current math style" while scanning, and there would be no need for `\mathchoice`, which is potentially expensive.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I fully agree. With a two argument `\frac` primitive, `\mathchoice` might be implemented as a four (maybe even eight, for the cramped styles) pronged conditional, making several problems much easier to solve, and without typesetting four boxes at each usage. Not to mention the “feature” that declarations in the numerator can leak in the denominator. Choosing an interface is always a balance between pros and cons; with `\over` the cons outnumber the pros.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yes, `\mathchoice` is not the best implementation of the problem. IMHO better would be something like `\write` node which is stored to the math list and expanded in the second pass over this math list. This node would create subtree in the math list and macro would know the current math style during this creation. But I am not Knuth, I didn't create TeX...

Answer (score 9):

Since you're using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), use `\binom{n-1}{|A_i|-1}` instead of `\choose`.

Answer (score 6):

The `\choose` macro have another syntax than usual in LaTeX (because it is plainTeX macro):

```
{above \choose below}
or
$above \choose below$
```

The first line shows why your code is bad and the third line shows why the simple `\choose` in math list `${n-1} \choose {|A_i|-1}$` works. But there are four redundant braces.

Solution: remove two braces and type:  `{n-1 \choose |A_i|-1}`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that braces that serve as argument delimiters for macros do so only once; in the macro expansion they are gone. In the example this applies to the braces around the second argument (denominator) of `\frac`: inside the expansion of `\frac` they are not part of that argument. This means that in writing the denominator you should not count on their presence, and write a separate pair of braces to make sure the reach of `\choose` is delimited to remain within that second argument.

When using `\choose` without such precaution in the arguments of other macros, you may end up having no errors but finding surrounding stuff added to the top and bottom indices of your binomial coefficient that don't belong there. Among other things it is to avoid such surprises that macro package writers encourage you to use `\frac` and `\binom` and friends.